# Adding to a list using another command

Tags: python, list

I have this script:

```
if line.startswith("Length="):
     #add line to list
```

I want to put each line that returns into a list as a separate element. How do I add one line at a time?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question. It is not clear how you are accessing your files or how you are writing to them. Or how you return you data to a list. We need the MCVE to really be able to help.

Comment: Generally, you'd use `.append()` or `.insert()`. However, more context is needed to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
my_list = []

for line in my_file:
    if line.startswith("Length="):
        my_list.append(line)
```

The method `append()` appends a passed obj into the existing list.

Example:

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>a.append(4)
>>>a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter a list or other iterable object and save all elements that match your criteria in a new list, you could use conditional list comprehension:

```py
original_list = ["Height=2", "Length=3", "Width=5", "Length=42"]
length_only = [item for item in original_list if item.startswith("Length=")]
```